# Populating ListBox with predefined layout

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone

I'm trying to populate a ListBox with Objects with a Predefined Layout, but I can't find a solid example. Here is what I currently do. Any tips would be appreciated.

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

PopulationCode:

```
List<JObject> json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(response);
for (int i = 0; i < json.Count(); i++)
{
    JObject location = json[i];
    pages.Add(new Page(location.GetValue("name").ToString(), location.GetValue("icon").ToString()));
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        if (this.listBox1 == null)
        {
            Out("list==null");
        }
        else if (pages == null)
        {
            Out("pages==null");
        }
        else
            listBox1.ItemsSource = pages;
    });
}
```

Data Object:

```
public partial class Page
{
    public String Name;
    public String Icon;

    public Page(String name, String icon)
    {
        Name = name;
        Icon = icon;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Icon' property not found on 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=45797138). BindingExpression: Path='Icon' DataItem='Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=45797138); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=45797138). BindingExpression: Path='Name' DataItem='Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=45797138); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Icon' property not found on 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=5425146). BindingExpression: Path='Icon' DataItem='Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=5425146); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=5425146). BindingExpression: Path='Name' DataItem='Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=5425146); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Icon' property not found on 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=5541955). BindingExpression: Path='Icon' DataItem='Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=5541955); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' 'Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=5541955). BindingExpression: Path='Name' DataItem='Mavie_Base.MainPage+Page' (HashCode=5541955); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
```

Comment: pages is an object with type List<page>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding to the public **field** not property that's exactly what the error message tell's you. Change your model's fields to properties:

```
public partial class Page
{
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public String Icon { get; private set; }

    public Page(String name, String icon)
    {
        Name = name;
        Icon = icon;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have assumed that a field is as much of a property as a function but then again i'm not a C# programmer. ♥u for helping me :p